# Verilog if-else-if syntax

Tags: verilog

I want to understand the `if else if` priority and working for Verilog.
In my code I can't seem to get to the 3rd condition and statement of the `if else if` construct. Why?

```
module alu #(parameter WIDTH=8) (in_a, in_b, opcode, alu_out, a_is_zero);
    input [2:0] opcode;
    input [WIDTH-1:0] in_a, in_b;
    output reg [WIDTH-1:0] alu_out;
    output reg a_is_zero;
    always @*
    begin
    a_is_zero=|in_a?0:1;
    if(opcode==000)begin
        alu_out=in_a; 
        end else if (opcode==001) begin
            alu_out=in_a; end
             else if(opcode==010) begin
                alu_out= in_b+in_a; end
                else begin alu_out=in_a; end            
    end 
endmodule
```

[image: failing to read the third condition-statement]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please explain the following integer constant used in verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108199/please-explain-the-following-integer-constant-used-in-verilog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `b` base specifier to your 3-bit constants.  In your code, `010` is the decimal value ten, not two.  You declared `opcode` as a 3-bit signal, which means it can have decimal values in the range 0-7.  Therefore, decimal 10 is not in the range, and `if(opcode==010)` will never be true. If a number is specified without a base, Verilog defaults to decimal format.

I added the `3'b` prefix to your 3 constants below:

```
if(opcode==3'b000)begin
    alu_out=in_a; 
    end else if (opcode==3'b001) begin
        alu_out=in_a; end
         else if(opcode==3'b010) begin
```